# Обращение к переменой вне класса

Tags: php

Что я делаю не так?

```
class cl {
  public static $arr = array();
}

$cl = new cl();
$cl->$arr['a'] = 1;

print_r($temp->$arr);
```

Comment: >Что я делаю не так?

Тыкаетесь наугад вместо чтения [руководств](http://www.php.su/learnphp/phpoo/?php5_2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пару решений задачи. Вам нужно начать с основ ООП, как предложил [[@klopp](/users/6550/klopp)](/users/6550/klopp)

```
class cl {
  private $arr = array('asdf','asdf');

  public function getArr(){
    return $this->arr;
  }

  public function setArr($key,$val){
    $this->arr[$key]=$val;
  }
}

$cl = new cl();
$cl->setArr('a',1);

print_r($cl->getArr());

class cl2 {
  private static $arr = array('asdf','asdf');
  public static function getArr(){
    return self::$arr;
  }

  public static function setArr($key,$val){
    self::$arr[$key]=$val;
  }
}

cl2::setArr('a',1);
print_r(cl2::getArr());
```

Comment: Я вот немного не понимаю, ладно, когда ещё переменную можно только получить, но делать get и set для одной переменной вообще какой смысл? Не легче использовать её как публичную?